# Couple and kids problem

Tags: probability

> Suppose a couple have $4$ children and let's assume the probability of having a boy is $0.6$. What is the probability that the fourth child is the third boy?

So all boys are the "same", this gives us three possible combinations

BBGB
GBBB
BGBB

Would the answer simply be $3(0.6)^3(1-0.6)^{4-3}$?

Comment: I guess so. $\binom {3}{1}*(0.6)^3(0.4)^1$

Comment: That's what I thought...

Comment: I mean you have given the right answer. Only three cases, the answer should be this.

Comment: I wrote 4 * what I had last night and it appeared right to me. Thanks

Comment: That is the answer for `3 boys for 4 children`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct there are only 3 possible ways for the 4th child to be the third boy

GBBB, BGBB, BBGB.

And the probability of any one of these will be $0.6^3 \times (1-0.6)$ because they all require 3 boys and one girl; only the order changes.  The probability is therefore:

$$3 \times 0.6^3 \times 0.4 = 0.2592 $$